# Jenkins matrix test results over different jobs

Tags: jenkins

My company has a set of big tests that take a while and are triggered at different times within 24 hours. I have created a plugin that converts the result of the log files of those test to JUnit XML files, so it can be transported to Jenkins.

For every branch and every customer combination, we have a job. All customers are grouped together into a multi-project Jenkins build per branch. An example looks like this:

[image]

Here is the problem: the results of the sanity tests will come in at different times a day per customer. Say that it starts with Customer A, while the other customers have no results yet. Jenkins will kick off every customer/sub-project, customer A will get its first results, and it will be nicely visible/browsable when you click on Customer A. You will see the amount of succeeded and failed tests. The other Customers have no test results because no XML files were generated by our custom plugin and found by Jenkins.

Next, customer C comes in. Jenkins will kick off the whole Project again,  and so all the sub-projects (all customers) will do the same thing.

However, I now have 2 options: 
1) I remove the old XML files in the workspace for Customer A. This way it won't run again, but if we now click on Customer A, it has also lost its test results, as it is in the previous build.
2) I don't remove the old XML files for every workspace. In this case Customer A will run again and do the same thing. In this case we lose regression status.

My question:
Is there a way to work around this? What I would really like is having the developer clicking on a Customer and it can see the results immediately without having lost its regression status for that day. I don't want the developer to look back in previous builds to search for the specific customer.

Comment: Are you saying you want to selectively run axis combinations based on which output is available?

Comment: Is that possible? Is it possible to say that every axis has to run individually but they all belong to the same build of its parent? That would help a lot yes.

Comment: I have one waiting to go but it needs a cosmetic fix in the matrix-plugin to show the form correctly when swapping execution strategies - saving and redisplaying fixes it. This gives a groovy script to decide which axis to run. https://github.com/jenkinsci/matrix-groovy-execution-strategy-plugin it needs to be built with `./gradlew jpi` as I haven't released it yet. It might do what you want